# Overlapping Charts VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, charts

Is there any way to create in vb.net a chart like this:

[image]

I have been searching for a while and couldn't find either a way to create a chart like that, or a method/control/property to join/overlap 2 different charts to get the above result.

So has anyone done this or knows a way of doing it, if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

I have used a product called [ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com) to create a similar chart before. It has the concept of "layers" so this type of chart can be created with two bar layers. May be the charting engine you are using has a similar concept.